# WordSegmentation in SymSpellPlusPlus

Tags: c++, pointers, spell-checking

I'd like to use C++ version of [SymSpell](https://github.com/wolfgarbe/SymSpell), which is called [SymSpellPlusPlus](https://github.com/erhanbaris/SymSpellPlusPlus). In C# version using WordSegmentation looks like this (from the first link):

```
//word segmentation and correction for multi-word input strings with/without spaces
inputTerm="thequickbrownfoxjumpsoverthelazydog";
maxEditDistance = 0;
suggestion = symSpell.WordSegmentation(input);

//display term and edit distance
Console.WriteLine(suggestion.correctedString + " " + suggestion.distanceSum.ToString("N0"));
```

In C++ version method WordSegmentation returns shared pointer (from the second link):

```
     ...
     shared_ptr<WordSegmentationItem> WordSegmentation(const char* input)
        {
            return WordSegmentation(input, this->maxDictionaryEditDistance, this->maxDictionaryWordLength);
        }

     shared_ptr<WordSegmentationItem> WordSegmentation(const char* input, size_t maxEditDistance)
        {
            return WordSegmentation(input, maxEditDistance, this->maxDictionaryWordLength);
        }

     shared_ptr<WordSegmentationItem> WordSegmentation(const char* input, size_t maxEditDistance, size_t maxSegmentationWordLength)
        {
          // lines 1039 - 1179 under second link
          std::vector<shared_ptr<WordSegmentationItem>> compositions;
          ...
          return compositions[circularIndex];
        }
```

In my code I tried among others the following code:

```
const char* inputTerm = "whereis th elove hehad dated forImuch of thepast who couqdn'tread in sixtgrade and ins pired him";
auto suggestions = symSpell.WordSegmentation(inputTerm);
```

But it gives an error:

```
free() invalid next size (fast)
```

It is related to memory error, but I don't know how to overcome this problem.
Class WordSegmentationItem looks as follows (lines 292-325 in second link):

```
class WordSegmentationItem
    {
    public:
        const char* segmentedString{ nullptr };
        const char* correctedString{ nullptr };
        u_int8_t distanceSum = 0;
        double probabilityLogSum = 0;

        WordSegmentationItem() { }
        WordSegmentationItem(const symspell::WordSegmentationItem & p)
        {
            this->segmentedString = p.segmentedString;
            this->correctedString = p.correctedString;
            this->distanceSum = p.distanceSum;
            this->probabilityLogSum = p.probabilityLogSum;
        }

        WordSegmentationItem& operator=(const WordSegmentationItem&) { return *this; }
        WordSegmentationItem& operator=(WordSegmentationItem&&) { return *this; }

        void set(const char* pSegmentedString, const char* pCorrectedString, u_int8_t pDistanceSum, double pProbabilityLogSum)
        {
            this->segmentedString = pSegmentedString;
            this->correctedString = pCorrectedString;
            this->distanceSum = pDistanceSum;
            this->probabilityLogSum = pProbabilityLogSum;
        }

        ~WordSegmentationItem()
        {
            delete[] segmentedString;
            delete[] correctedString;
        }
};
```

How should I get the correctedString from the WordSegmentationItem?

Comment: Seems like this is a question/bug report for the library authors.

Comment: ([and they have priors](https://github.com/erhanbaris/SymSpellPlusPlus/issues/3))

Comment: ((guessing [this](https://github.com/erhanbaris/SymSpellPlusPlus/issues/6) was you!))

Comment: It wasn't me :)

Comment: Same input string, same question, same problem, same day! Hmm

Comment: You probably asked about [this] (https://github.com/erhanbaris/SymSpellPlusPlus/issues/6). It was me :)

Comment: That's what I linked to yes

Comment: OK. I've notice that author of SymSpellPlusPlus doesn't respond too often. That's way I asked here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The library is buggy and the author needs to make some fixes.

First, compiling gives us a warning about `SuggestItem::ShallowCopy`, which returns a local variable by reference. Very bad! We can change that to return by value, probably.

This doesn't fix the crash, though.

If we clone the library's repo then run the following testcase in a debugger:

```
#include "symspell6.h"

int main()
{
    const char* inputTerm = "whereis th elove hehad dated forlmuch of thepast who couqdn'tread in sixtgrade and ins pired him";

    symspell::SymSpell symSpell;
    auto suggestions = symSpell.WordSegmentation(inputTerm);
}
```

…we see that returning `compositions[circularIndex]` from the `WordSegmentation` function is causing an invalid access in the `shared_ptr` constructor. This suggests that `circularIndex` is out-of-bounds and giving us a non-existent `shared_ptr`. Indeed, `circularIndex` is `95` but `compositions.size()` is `0`!

The function is lacking some serious error checking.

Now, only the author (or at least someone who knows what the library is supposed to do; that's not me!) can fix this properly. But as a quick patch I added the following after line 1055:

```
if (compositions.empty())
   return nullptr;
```

…and it now at least runs.

It seems that the function assumes the dictionary is non-empty. I don't know whether that's expected behaviour or not (other than the missing error checking as detailed above).

The project is in serious need of some documentation, because no preconditions or postconditions are mentioned for these functions and there is no indication as to how the library is supposed to be used. Again, the author should fix these things.

Comment: I raised an Issue on github for the dangling reference.